# How can the bot edit its message after three seconds or a period of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have this piece of code but I am not entirely sure on how the bot will wait for 3 seconds before it edit its mesaage.

```
   message.channel.send("Test").then((msg) => {
       msg.edit("test1")
       msg.edit("test2")
    });
```

Comment: Do you want it to wait for 3 seconds before it edits the message to "test2" ?

Comment: I think you can maybe use setInterval()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript there are two main functions involving time. Being `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. `setTimeout` allows a specified function to be invoked after a set time, which is what I believe you are trying to do. `setInterval` invokes a function repetitively every `n` milliseconds specified. If you wanted the bot the wait for 3 seconds before it edits the message to "test2",

```
 message.channel.send("Test").then((msg) => {
    msg.edit("test1")
    setTimeout(msg.edit("test2"), 3*1000); // 3secs as 3*1000 as it's in milliseconds
 })
```

This code will result in the bot sending a message "Test", instantly editing it to "test1" and 3 seconds later to "test2".